# Indention: Disable (Globally)

Tags: beamer, formatting, paragraphs

**Problem**

Given the `beamer` class.

Can I remove indention globally?

`\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` didn't work out.

**Example**

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\visible<1->{
Some formula:
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$}
\visible<2->{
More formulas:
$$z=a+ib=re^{i\phi}$$
Some text.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `bemaer` doesn't indent text by default. Can you provide a simple document showing this indentation you want to suppress?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Oh so it might be hidden a some template I loaded. Unfortunately, it will be hard to track back where. Is it possible to set it manually?

Comment: It depends on what the settings in that template are. Can you provide a link to the template?

Comment: I got a miniexample. I'll add it to the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware of superfluous empty spaces (a line break in the code tantamount to a blank space); I commented out those spaces below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\visible<1->{%
Some formula:
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
}%
\visible<2->{%
More formulas:
\[z=a+ib=re^{i\phi}\]
Some text.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX documents; use `\[...\]` instead; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/3954).

Comment: When exactly do I need to take care of these? If it ends with `{` or `}`?

Comment: In your case, following the open brace for an argument or right after the closing brace of an argument.

Comment: And what about the lines in between?

Comment: @Freeze_S Which lines in between? Do you mean one or more blank lines in the code? In that case, there's no problem since in text mode they tantamount to `\par` (ending a paragraph.)

Comment: For example the lines `\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]` and `\[z=a+ib=re^{i\phi}\]`?

Comment: @Freeze_S There you don't need special care since `\[...\]` and displayed environments for maths begin and end their own paragraphs.

Comment: Aha is it like if I would whyever start with `\[a^2+b^2=c^2` and end this in a new line with `\]` then I'll need a `%`?

Comment: @Freeze_S No; under normal circumstances in environments for displayed maths that is not necessary. (The only precaution there is not to leave blank lines: leaving a blank line between `c^2` and the closing `\]` will trigger an error).

Comment: @Freeze_S perhaps this can be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/3954.

Comment: Didn't got all of it but a little. Thanks!! :)